# Регулярные выражения: проверить несоответствие формату

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

Я хочу написать регэкс, который соответствует путям к файлам без расширений. Регулярное выражение, соответвующее путям с расширениями, я составил так: `\w*\.\w+$`. Например, оно соответствует `.mp3`, но не соответствует `mp3`. А как сделать отрицание? То есть проверить обратное утверждение: путь не оканчивается строкой такого вида.

Высокоуровневые языки не используются. Это регулярка для nginx.

Comment: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?10,230949,238999#msg-238999

Comment: `^[^.]+$` - если нужно выражение, которое возвращает совпадение только тогда, когда в тексте нет точки. Если нужно выражение, чтобы находило совпадение, если строка состоит только из букв/цифр и подчеркивания -   `^\w+$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!preg_match('/\w*\.\w+$/', $filepath)){
    echo 'Does not match';
}
```

Либо расширьте свой вопрос.

Comment: Высокоуровневые языки не используются. Это регулярка для nginx.

Comment: Что-то типа такого `(?!\w*\.\w+$)` но надо тестить

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, что-то такое:

```
\/[^.]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваше регулярное выражение неэффективно для файлов с расширением. За более правильным решением я бы зашел [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624870/regex-get-filename-without-extension-in-one-shot)

Насчет самой проблемы:

Может, сделаем проще и просто экранированную точку уберем? :D

Ведь противопоставление файлу с расширением ,то есть, с точкой  - это файл без расширения, то есть без точки, следуя вашему случаю и моей логике :D

Условимся,  что мы решили пользоваться вашим regex и ,пути задаются символом '/'.

Тогда можно вот такое сделать ( не с компа, но должно  сработать)

/\w+$

Если совпадет, то вот вам и отрицание, которое вы хотели.

Но имена файлов могут и пробелы содержать, поэтому, если бы я хотел эффективное регулярное выражение со словами, разделенные пробелами, то я бы заглянул [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472764/regular-expression-to-allow-spaces-between-words)